# Program creates .db file on root level automatically

Tags: database, typescript, sqlite, electron

I'm building a electron, typescript, react app with sqlite as database. You can see the minimalistic visualization of the directory here:

```
├── build
│   ├── electron
│   │   ├── electron.js
│   │   └── preload.js
│   └── src
│       └── db
│           └── dbMgr.js
├── electron
│   ├── electron.ts
│   ├── preload.ts
│   
├── src
    ├── db
        ├── dbMgr.ts
        └── testDB.db
```

**main in package.json**

`main: "build/electron/electron.js"`

**in dbMgr.ts**

```ts
new sqlite3.Database('./testDB.db', (err: error) => {
          //...
       });
```

`electron.ts` imports `dbMgr.ts`

**Upon starting**

A new `.db` file is created on root level (`./src`) and an error shows up that it couldn't find the original database file.
In the `/built` directory, it now also created a path to the `dbMgr.js` file.

After the first start fails (but creates a new .db file on root level), second start no longer fails and is now working with that new created .db file

How can I make sure that the .db file stays where it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert at this, but I think you have to put `testDB.db` like the following:

[image]